# How to write Nepali and English on the same page in Overleaf

Tags: fontspec, polyglossia, grid-typesetting, devanagari

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{Nepali}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Nepali}
\newfontfamily\devtransl[Mapping=DevRom]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\foreignlanguage{Nepali}
\section*{शोघसा}
मेटल अर्गानिक फ्रेमवर्कहरू (MOFs)  धातु आयन र   लिङ्कर भनिने जैविक अणु(जो धातु आयनहरूमा बाँधिएका  हुन्छन्) को हाइब्रिड नेटवर्कबाट बनेको क्रिस्टलीय ठोसहरू हुन्। मेटल अर्गानिक फ्रेमवर्कहरू  (MOFs) तिनीहरूको ठूलो सतह क्षेत्र, ठूलो सतह आयतन अनुपात र उच्च छिद्रता र संरचनात्मक लचिलोपनका कारण अत्यधिक आकर्षक छन्। विगत धेरै वर्षहरूमा, MOFs ले हाइड्रोजन ऊर्जाको क्षेत्रमा ठूलो ध्यान आकर्षित गरेको छ,विशेष गरी हाइड्रोजन भण्डारणको
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Welcome to the site! The MWE is great, but I would have appreciated a few words of explanation about what you wanted. For example, whether it was important to use `polyglossia` and XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 5):

Your question doesn’t say much about what you want, but you appear to be trying to use `babel` commands incorrectly.  You seem to want `\selectlanguage`, not `\foreignlanguage`.  Also, you’re trying to load Nepali in `polyglossia`, which doesn’t support it, and then use `babel`.

In LuaLaTeX, this should work for you.  I replaced a font I don’t have with Noto Serif Devanagari, but you can substitute any font of your choice.

```
\documentclass{report}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Error if language detection fails!
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=sectioning, nil]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\emergencystretch=3em % Compensate for lack of hyphenation.

\babelprovide[import=en, main, onchar=fonts ids]{english}
\babelprovide[import=ne, onchar=fonts ids]{nepali}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\babelfont{rm}
          [Language=Default]{Times New Roman}
\babelfont[nepali]{rm}
          [Language=Default, Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Noto Serif Devanagari}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{Nepali}

\section*{शोघसा} मेटल अर्गानिक फ्रेमवर्कहरू (MOFs) धातु आयन र लिङ्कर भनिने जैविक अणु(जो धातु आयनहरूमा बाँधिएका हुन्छन्) को हाइब्रिड नेटवर्कबाट बनेको क्रिस्टलीय ठोसहरू हुन्। मेटल अर्गानिक फ्रेमवर्कहरू (MOFs) तिनीहरूको ठूलो सतह क्षेत्र, ठूलो सतह आयतन अनुपात र उच्च छिद्रता र संरचनात्मक लचिलोपनका कारण अत्यधिक आकर्षक छन्। विगत धेरै वर्षहरूमा, MOFs ले हाइड्रोजन ऊर्जाको क्षेत्रमा ठूलो ध्यान आकर्षित गरेको छ,विशेष गरी हाइड्रोजन भण्डारणको
\end{document}
```

[image: Noto Serif Devanagari sample]

**ETA:** As of 2022, LuaLaTeX needs `Renderer=Harfbuzz` to display Nepali with Noto Sans Devanagari.  Other fonts might not want this, or `Language=Default`.

However, in an earlier edit, you appeared to be loading a font with the `Mapping=` feature, implying that you are in fact using XeLaTeX.  Unfortunately, auto-detecting the language you’re typing in with `ucharclasses` doesn’t work well when switching between left-to-right and right-to-left scripts within a group, but here is a MWE that defines a `\MOFs` macro for the one English acronym you use:

```
\documentclass{report}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Error if the language is incorrectly set!
\usepackage[bidi=default, nil]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xspace}

\emergencystretch=3em % Compensate for lack of hyphenation.

\babelprovide[import=en, main]{english}
\babelprovide[import=ne]{nepali}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\babelfont{rm}[Language=Default]{Times New Roman}
\babelfont[nepali]{rm}[Language=Default]{Noto Serif Devanagari}

\newcommand{\MOFs}{\foreignlanguage{english}{MOFs}\xspace}

\begin{document}
\begin{otherlanguage}{nepali}

\section*{शोघसा}

मेटल अर्गानिक फ्रेमवर्कहरू (\MOFs) धातु आयन र लिङ्कर भनिने जैविक अणु(जो धातु आयनहरूमा बाँधिएका हुन्छन्) को हाइब्रिड नेटवर्कबाट बनेको क्रिस्टलीय ठोसहरू हुन्। मेटल अर्गानिक फ्रेमवर्कहरू (\MOFs) तिनीहरूको ठूलो सतह क्षेत्र, ठूलो सतह आयतन अनुपात र उच्च छिद्रता र संरचनात्मक लचिलोपनका कारण अत्यधिक आकर्षक छन्। विगत धेरै वर्षहरूमा, \MOFs ले हाइड्रोजन ऊर्जाको क्षेत्रमा ठूलो ध्यान आकर्षित गरेको छ,विशेष गरी हाइड्रोजन भण्डारणको

\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Noto Serif Devanagari sample]

Comment: actually i am very new to latex and i am trying to write thesis paper using templetes.i cant figureout what changes to made in preamble and what changes should be made in section.I tried above code but it doesnot work

Comment: @RoshniSharma Evertyhing above `\begin{document}` is the preamble.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the text you want to write in English using `\textenglish` or between `\begin{english}` and `\end{english}`.