# LuaLaTeX fails to render Nepali properly, how can I fix it?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, babel

I'm not that hot with fontspec and friends, so took most from this answer about Nepali verbatim:

[How to write Nepali and English on the same page in Overleaf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638161/how-to-write-nepali-and-english-on-the-same-page-in-overleaf/638172#638172)

Here's my slightly edited code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Error if language detection fails!
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=sectioning, nil]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\emergencystretch=3em % Compensate for lack of hyphenation.

\babelprovide[import=en, main, onchar=fonts ids]{english}
\babelprovide[import=ne, onchar=fonts ids]{nepali}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\babelfont{rm}[Language=Default]{Noto Sans}
\babelfont[nepali]{rm}[Language=Default]{Noto Sans Devanagari}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=2cm]{word}

\Large

\foreignlanguage{nepali}{फ्राई}
\end{document}
```

And here is `word.png`, which should render as "फ्राई":

[image]

I notice in a cruel twist that they look similar here, but they certainly do not when I run this.

Comment: you need the harfbuzz renderer: `\babelfont[nepali]{rm}[Language=Default,Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Noto Sans Devanagari}`

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ulrike Fischer answered in the comments, you need the Harfbuzz renderer in LuaLaTeX with Noto Sans Devanagari.  Add it as an option when loading Noto Sans Devanagari.

```
\documentclass{report}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Error if language detection fails!
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=sectioning, nil]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\emergencystretch=3em % Compensate for lack of hyphenation.

\babelprovide[import=en, main, onchar=fonts ids]{english}
\babelprovide[import=ne, onchar=fonts ids]{nepali}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\babelfont{rm}
          [Language=Default]{Noto Sans}
\babelfont[nepali]{rm}
          [Language=Default, Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Noto Sans Devanagari}

\begin{document}

% \includegraphics[width=2cm]{word}

\Large

\foreignlanguage{nepali}{फ्राई}
\end{document}
```

[image: Noto Sans Devanagari sample]

I’ve edited the fix into my previous answer that you linked. Thank you for finding this bug.